# awk - Rounding to 2 decimal places in subtotals

Tags: awk, rounding

Short version:

Is there a way to tell awk to round to 2 decimal places during the consolidation, not during the printing?

Long version:

I have an incoming file in the format below. I should get the net balances per currency and if the net is NOT zero, print the result in two columns: net balances less than zero go to neg_bal column and positive balances go to pos_bal column. For some reason, the USD column is still being printed despite netting to zero

```
JPY||170
JPY||40
USD|-42.61|
USD|-166.27
USD||42.61|
GBP|-20|
EUR||18.7
USD||174.6|
USD|-8.33||
EUR|-30.6|
GBP||100
JPY|-210|
```

Here is the code am using:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS="|";
    }
    {
    bal[$1]+=$2+$3
    ccy[$1]=$1
    }
END {
    for (i in ccy)
        {
        if (bal[i] >0 )
        {
            pos_bal = bal[i]
            neg_bal = 0
        }
        else
        {
            neg_bal  = bal[i]
            pos_bal  = 0
        }
        if (bal[i] != 0 )
            {
                printf "%s|%.2f|%.2f\n",ccy[i],neg_bal,pos_bal
            }       
        }
    }
```

Result (notice JPY is not displayed since it nets to zero):

```
awk]$ ./scr1 file1
EUR|-11.90|0.00
USD|0.00|0.00
GBP|0.00|80.00
```

If I increase the decimal places to say, 20, I see that the USD net amount is not really zero. (Why is this, btw? Even excel gives a net of -1.59872E-14)

```
awk]$ ./scr1 file1
EUR|-11.90000000000000213163|0.00000000000000000000
USD|0.00000000000000000000|0.00000000000001243450
GBP|0.00000000000000000000|80.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: wrt "why is this" - because it's a floating point calculation, google it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell awk to round to 2 decimal places during the
>   consolidation, not during the printing?

Yes: multiply by 100 and convert to int. Then divide by 100 when you're ready to print.

(In other words, count pennies instead of dollars.)